# libpq + xcode: how to compile

Tags: xcode, postgresql, libpq

ALL,

I recently bought myself a new Mac and started testing my application with the latest PostgreSQL + libpq.

I built libpq (only) from sources and installed it according to the following:

1. ./configure
2. cd interface/src/libpq
3. make
4. sudo make install

Everything worked but now I need to add -I and -L/-l options to the XScode project.

[This](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/libpq-build.html) link talks about using either pkg-config or pg_config. I don't have pkg-config because this is not Linux, and neither do have pg_config.

So what is the best way to build and test the program on Mac that should link with libpq?

TIA!